# Product stock inventory

Tags: product, products-management, products, stock, inventory

I have a problem I need help with, it's probably very simple but I just can't understand.
So, I am trying to make a product called "Silver Fork" that I sell for 10$. But I also want to offer the customer to buy 3 forks for 25$ and another option if he buys 5 forks, for 35$.

I´ve created a "Simple product", and under "Custom Options". I put in the values and everything works out fine, execept the inventory. If a customer buys the option with 3 forks the inventory doesnt go down with 3 pieces, it goes down with 1 piece, same problem if the customer chooses the option to buy 5 forks.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Sara,you can use the `tier price`,Where magento have provide `qty wise price verity`.
More details on tier price on http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing 
Tier can be set from Admin
[image]

Frontend view of tier price

[image]

Comment: The solution provided by @AmitBera is the correct approach to your question. If you want more information on product setup I would recommend reading the Magento user manual http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide_v.1.9.pdf tier prices are covered on pages 206-207